# Unable to do head or tail for a file

Tags: linux, csv, newlines, file-format

I have a .CSV file which upon passing the `file test_file.csv` command gives the output as:

```
test_file.csv: ISO-8859 English text, with CR line terminators
```

When I am using `cat, head or tail` command on the file, it is returning me the total file content on the screen. How do I convert the line terminators so that I will be able to use these commands and use the file for further processing. Also, I was wondering if there is a way to know how this file was generated/created? Please suggest.

Comment: Please add the output of `LANG=C wc -l test_file.csv` and `locale`.

Comment: The output for **`LANG=C wc -l test_file.csv`** gives: **`0 test_file.csv`** and  **`locale`** gives: **`LANG=en_US
LC_CTYPE="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_PAPER="C"
LC_NAME="C"
LC_ADDRESS="C"
LC_TELEPHONE="C"
LC_MEASUREMENT="C"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="C"
LC_ALL=C`**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only thing I'm aware of that commonly used a bare `CR` as a line terminator is old Mac systems (before Mac OS X) but unless it's a really old file that seems unlikely.

In any case the `mac2unix` program in the `dos2unix` package should be able to fix it for you.

Answer (score 2):

The `file` command is showing you that the file's character set is ISO-8859 English text, you can use the command `iconv` to convert files from one character set to another.

#### Example

To begin with we have the following file.

```
$ file a.srt 
a.srt: ISO-8859 English text, with CRLF line terminators
```

Now let's convert the file from `ISO-8859-15` to `utf-8`. Here we're taking file `a.srt` to `b.srt`.

```
$ iconv -f ISO-8859-15 -t utf-8 a.srt > b.srt
```

Now the new file `b.srt` is in `UTF-8` format.

```
$ file b.srt 
b.srt: UTF-8 Unicode English text, with CRLF line terminators
```

#### What about the CRLF line terminators?

These are typical of files that come from a PC. On a PC, end of lines are terminated with a carriage return and a line feed. You can see these characters if you use a tool such as `hexdump`.

#### Example

```
hexdump -C b.srt | head -5
00000000  31 0d 0a 30 30 3a 30 30  3a 31 36 2c 33 30 32 20  |1..00:00:16,302 |
00000010  2d 2d 3e 20 30 30 3a 30  30 3a 31 39 2c 36 38 30  |--> 00:00:19,680|
00000020  0d 0a 3c 69 3e 54 68 65  20 63 69 74 79 27 73 20  |..<i>The city's |
00000030  63 61 6c 6c 65 64 20 44  75 6b 65 0d 0a 54 68 65  |called Duke..The|
00000040  20 73 74 61 74 65 27 73  20 63 61 6c 6c 65 64 20  | state's called |
```

Notice the character sequence `0d 0a` . These are the "CR line terminators" referenced in the `file` commands output. You can use a tool such as `dos2unix` to remove these.

```
$ dos2unix -n b.srt c.srt
dos2unix: converting file b.srt to file c.srt in UNIX format ...
```

Now when we look at the resulting file for `dos2unix`, `c.srt`.

```
$ hexdump -C c.srt | head -5
00000000  31 0a 30 30 3a 30 30 3a  31 36 2c 33 30 32 20 2d  |1.00:00:16,302 -|
00000010  2d 3e 20 30 30 3a 30 30  3a 31 39 2c 36 38 30 0a  |-> 00:00:19,680.|
00000020  3c 69 3e 54 68 65 20 63  69 74 79 27 73 20 63 61  |<i>The city's ca|
00000030  6c 6c 65 64 20 44 75 6b  65 0a 54 68 65 20 73 74  |lled Duke.The st|
00000040  61 74 65 27 73 20 63 61  6c 6c 65 64 20 4e 65 77  |ate's called New|
```

Notice the `0d 0a` sequence from the `b.srt` file have been converted to `0a`. This character is how end of lines are terminated on Unix systems.

Now when we check the file `c.srt` using `file` take note that the file no longer is reported as being terminated with CRLF line terminators.

```
$ file c.srt 
c.srt: UTF-8 Unicode English text
```

#### What about the CR line terminators?

As [@TomH's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/108293/7453) touches on, a file that terminates using just a CR, is from a Mac. To make the point clear.

`CR` and `LF` are characters, respectively coded `0x0D` (13 decimal) and `0x0A` (10 decimal). They are used to mark a line break in text files.

- Windows uses two characters, i.e. `CR LF` sequence
- Unix only uses `LF`
- MacIntosh used `CR`

When Apple switched to using OSX (which is based on BSD) they switched to also using `LF`, given BSD is rooted in Unix.

See the Wikipedia topic Newlines which has a section on [Representations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representations), it covers all the different system's and their corresponding new line characters.

#### References

- [How can I change the encoding of a subtitle file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/277565/how-can-i-change-the-encoding-of-a-subtitle-file)
- [Wikipedia - Newline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline)

Comment: Character encodings have nothing to do with it.  Also, DOS/Windows systems produce line terminators using both CR and LF.  The file in question has *only* CR line terminators, which suggests it was produced by a classic Mac system.

Comment: @AGWA - You're missing the point of my A. What I am stating is showing the 2 components of the output from `file`. One aspect is the encoding the other is the CR or CRLF nature of the line termination. I do not have a ancient Mac to duplicate those file types, so I'm showing more of the details. TomH's answer already mentioned the mac2unix tool, but left many of the details untouched, so I'm attempting to show some of the mechanics.

Comment: +1 Some great information here slm... thank you for sharing...

Comment: @Dhruuv - sure thing, TomH's answer told you the gist of why, I was trying to give you more of full picture of why and also break down some of the magic.